# Magento 500 Internal Server - No Log Files?

Tags: magento-1.9, permissions, error-log, http-error-500

I have just upgraded my site from Magento 1.7 to 1.9 and i'm now getting a 500 Internal Server Error. From other posts, I have done the following:

- Deleted the maintenance.flag file
- Changed permission on index.php to 755
- Changed permission on downloader/index.php to 755
- Changed permissions recursively on /var to 777
- I've also gone through the files and all directories seem to be 755 and all main files '666'.

I'm still getting the 500 Internal Server Error. The bigger problem is that I have no error files in /log to be able to identify the problem. I created the folder /log (because it didn't exist) but no files are in there. I do not have access to the frontend of backend (because of the 500 Internal Server Error) to make sure that logging is turned on.

Any idea how I can try to troubleshoot / get these error logs?

**Edit:** My server error log shows the error `Premature end of script headers: index.php`.

Comment: What's the server setup? What version of PHP do you use? It sounds like PHP is having some issues.

Comment: How is this off-topic?